# #1235 - Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Tags: sql, mariadb

Cree este trigger que verifica antes de hacer la actualizacion del precio, si el precio es menor que 0 o mayor que 1000, si en el primer caso es verdadero entonces lo deja el precio en 0 y si es el otro caso lo deja en 100

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER REVISA_PRECIO_BU BEFORE UPDATE ON productos FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
 IF(NEW.PRECIO<0) THEN
 
 SET NEW.PRECIO=0;

ELSEIF (NEW.PRECIO>1000) THEN
SET NEW.PRECIO=1000; 

END IF;

END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Sin embargo cuando ejecuto el trigger me sale este mensaje

> #1235 - Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, se evidencia que el motor de base de datos que utilizás es _MariaDB_ (hermano de MySQL), por lo tanto pulsa en [edit] y descarta las etiquetas no relacionadas (incluso PHPMyAdmin). Además, leyendo el mensaje de error: ¿estás seguro/a que no tenés otro trigger para la misma tabla que haga un `before update`?

Comment: pero si es phpmyadmin no mariadb, por otro lado soy principiante en sql y phpmyadmin, cuantos triggers soportaria? solo 1? si tengo la misma instruccion before update? o lo tendria que agregar a esa misma, lo digo porque he visto que si sucede esto le agregue esta nueva instruccion al trigger que ya tengo

Comment: @anonymuus_gp phpmyadmin solo es la interfaz mediante la cual trabajas con tus bases de datos, dicha interfaz necesita que exista un servidor de bases de datos (**mariadb**) funcionando y encendido en tu computadora en este caso

Comment: Casi seguro que tienes otro(s) TRIGGER(s) que se está(n) disparando. Ejecuta esta consulta y revisa si hay otros TRIGGER que interfieren con este: `SHOW TRIGGERS
FROM aquíElNombreDeLaBaseDeDatos
WHERE table = 'productos';`